# How to connect to an Amazon MySQL RDS instance via PHP over SSL

Tags: php, ssl, amazon-ec2, mysqli, amazon-rds

I have an EC2 instance running a WordPress site.  The WordPress db is on a RDS instance.  I want to connect to the db over SSL.

From what I've read, the MySQL extension that WordPress uses out of the box doesn't support SSL.  So, I've installed a WordPress db script that uses MySQLi, which does support SSL.

The problem I encountered is that Amazon only supplies one key file ([more info](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/index.html?Concepts.DBInstance.html#Concepts.DBEngine.MySQL51.SSLSupport)), and all the examples I can find using MySQLi over SSL include at least 3 files:

```
$db = mysqli_init();
$db->ssl_set('server-key.pem','server-cert.pem','cacert.pem',NULL,NULL);
```

I'm able to connect to my db over SSL from the mysql command line app.  Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get PHP's MySQLi extension to work, given that I only have the 1 file?

Comment: What happens if you skip those parameters?

Comment: Just a note, Amazon docs state that within the same Region traffic does never leave Amazon's network. So this includes traffic between all Availability Zones within one particular Region.

Comment: Also, what was the name/link of the "WordPress db script that uses MySQLi"? Thanks!

Comment: It's been a while but I believe I followed these instructions to modify wp-db.php: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/mysqli

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out this was less complicated than I thought.  Turning up the error reporting level uncovered an error in my code that I hadn't caught.  Using ssl_set this way works:

```
$db = mysqli_init();
$db->ssl_set(NULL,NULL,'/path/to/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem',NULL,NULL);
$db->real_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname);
```

Comment: doesnt EC2 already come with this mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem file preinstalled or do you need to manually download and install it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$db = mysqli_init();
$db->ssl_set(null, 'https://rds.amazonaws.com/doc/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem', null, null, null);
```