# Connect AWS EC2 instance to RDS MySQL through SSL using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ssl, mysqli, amazon-ec2

I am unable to make my AWS EC2 instance connect to my RDS MySQL DB through SSL.

AWS EC2 Linux 2, Apache 2.4.39, PHP 7.3.10, MySQL 5.7.26.
In order for my application that resides in EC2 to have a secure connection in transit, it must utilize SSL/TLS. My understanding that given my PHP/MySQL application, I need to perform the code below. In order not to affect my DB, I have set up a test DB. The new user is called new-user with its own password. I got the bundled PEM file rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem from https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem and placed it in a browser accessible directory on the EC2 server as directed by that AWS page.

Any ideas why "Unable to set private key file `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem' " in the output?

````
**In AWS-test-ssl-script.php** ..

20 define ('MYSQLI', 'AWS-test-connect.php');

**In 'AWS-test-connect.php'** ..

12 $dbc=mysqli_init();
13 mysqli_ssl_set($dbc, NULL, "/dir/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem", NULL, NULL, NULL);
14 mysqli_real_connect($dbc,"DB_server","new-user","password");

16 $res = mysqli_query($dbc, 'SHOW STATUS like "Ssl_cipher"');
17 print_r(mysqli_fetch_row($res));
18 mysqli_close($dbc);

**In AWS-test-ssl-script.php** ..

35 require(MYSQLI);

44 $sel = "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'new-user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' REQUIRE SSL";
45 $sel_qry = mysqli_query($dbc, $sel);
46 mysqli_close($sel_qry);

48 $grant = "GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
49 ON testdb
50 TO new-user@%";
51 $grant_qry = mysqli_query($dbc, $grant);
52 mysqli_close($grant_qry);```

Output ..
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): Unable to set private key file `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem' in AWS-test-connect.php on line 14
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): Cannot connect to MySQL by using SSL in AWS-test-connect.php on line 14
plus other warnings.
````

Comment: here you can find the solution.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695650/how-to-connect-to-an-amazon-mysql-rds-instance-via-php-over-ssl/4696366#4696366)

Comment: @Shohag Monzur Using the code you referenced got the warning: Warning: mysqli::real_connect(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /path/AWS-test-connect.php on line 14

Answer (score 1):

It's a PHP  mysqli_real_connect() error reporting that the specified SSL key cannot be found.

That key is referenced in  this statement on line 13:

```
 mysqli_ssl_set($dbc, NULL, "/dir/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

That message suggests that key file does not exist, or has incorrect permissions. Can you confirm that file is accessible in that directory?

You could also turn off SSL if it's not crucial and see if that works.

Comment: SSL off makes no difference. I confirmed the file exists with file_exists(). I tried permissions of 660, 770, and 664 with the group as apache. Do you see any permission issues there? Also, the pem file location is not browser accessible, it's in a private directory. And the same warnings.

Comment: Can you show the results of `ls -l /dir/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` and `ls -ld /dir`?

Comment: ```-rwxrwx--- 1 root apache 65484 Jan 2 22:12 /dir/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
and
drwxrws--- 11 ec2-user apache 4096 Jan 8 16:33 /dir```

Comment: I would set both the file and directory to 777 and try again.

Comment: Same output. ```Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /dir/AWS-test-connect.php on line 14```

Comment: Oh .. I had changed set to ```mysqli_ssl_set($dbc, NULL, NULL, NULL, '/dir/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem', NULL); ``` since according to the rules a pem file should be in this position vs the original one above.

Comment: Note carefully: That's a different error than what your first output shows. It is a verify failed error now.  It appears we have fixed the permissions problem. Now it's something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205834/discussion-between-krot-and-rodrigo-m).