# Connect AWS EC2 instance to RDS MySQL through SSL using PHP #2

Tags: php, ssl, mysqli, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

This is a different question than a previous one by the same title.

I am unable to make my AWS EC2 instance connect to my RDS MySQL DB through SSL.

AWS EC2 Linux 2, Apache 2.4.39, PHP 7.3.10, MySQL 5.7.26

In order for my application that resides in EC2 to have a secure connection in transit, it must utilize SSL/TLS. My understanding that given my PHP/MySQL application, I need to perform the code below. In order not to affect my DB, I have set up a test DB. The new user is called new-user with its own password. I got the bundled PEM file rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem from https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem and placed it in a browser accessible directory on the EC2 server as directed by that AWS page.

Any ideas what I need to change with mysqli_real_connect() and any other statements in order to allow the database to be accessed?

**In AWS-test-ssl-script.php ..**

```
20 define ('MYSQLI', 'AWS-test-connect.php');
```

**In 'AWS-test-connect.php' ..**

```
12 $dbc=mysqli_init();

13 mysqli_ssl_set($dbc, NULL, NULL, NULL, "/dir/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem", NULL);
14 mysqli_real_connect($dbc,"DB_server[without :port#]","new-user","password", "db-name", "port#");

16 $res = mysqli_query($dbc, 'SHOW STATUS like "Ssl_cipher"');
17 print_r(mysqli_fetch_row($res));
18 mysqli_close($dbc);
```

**In AWS-test-ssl-script.php ..**

```
35 require(MYSQLI);

44 $sel = "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'new-user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' REQUIRE SSL";
45 $sel_qry = mysqli_query($dbc, $sel);
46 mysqli_close($sel_qry);

48 $grant = "GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
49 ON testdb
50 TO new-user@%";
51 $grant_qry = mysqli_query($dbc, $grant);
52 mysqli_close($grant_qry);
```

**Output ..**

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /dir/AWS-test-connect.php on line 14
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): Cannot connect to MySQL by using SSL in /dir/AWS-test-connect.php on line 14
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): [2002] (trying to connect via (null)) in /dir/AWS-test-connect.php on line 14
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): in /dir/AWS-test-connect.php on line 14
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to an Amazon MySQL RDS instance via PHP over SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695650/how-to-connect-to-an-amazon-mysql-rds-instance-via-php-over-ssl)

Comment: @matesio Not really. Line 13 handles locating the pem file.

Comment: Are you sure mysqli_ssl_set is able to read the pem file and importing the certificates?  The pem doesn't need to be accessed by the browser only by the php code.

Comment: To determine if the pem file was definitely accessible, I opened the permissions to prevent any of them negating access, and checked the locations and parameters ..

ls -l /dir/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem shows 
rwxrwxrwx root apache date /dir/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem

and ..

    ls -ld /dir shows

drwxrwsrwx ec2-user apache date /dir

How would I find out if mysqli_ssl_set is able to read the pem file and importing the certificates?

Comment: Then file_exists("/dir/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem");

And it gave '1'